# What is the preferred beacon advertising format

Tags: ibeacon, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

We are planning to integrate a BLE compatible Bluetooth module on one of our product hardware. For the last few days I have been digging around the net and got a fair idea about the technology. Now that I have an understanding of the tech, I think we have a choice of going with either of iBeacon, AltBeacon or Eddystone as the advertising format.

Please note that we would not be approaching a BLE vendor but instead we would be approaching a chip manufacturer like Texas instruments or somebody who would be delivering our original hardware. The Bluetooth module is a last minute addendum.I guess chip manufacturers would be open to work with any of the advertising formats as we suggest them (this is my guess. I have no clue on this). But let's say if they are, which would be the preferred format to go with ??

**My 2 cents -**

- I understand iBeacon compatible devices would have some kind of a
  cert process from apple. We want to avoid any kind of mandatory cert
  process. As I mentioned the Bluetooth module is only an addendum for
  us.
- iBeacon seems to be the most mature since it has been around for a while
- AltBeacon looks to be almost similar to iBeacon with a bit of more flexibility and sans the Apple luggage. Is there any cert required by
  the owners i.e. Radius Networks ??
- Eddystone looks to be the most robust and future proof. Again is there a cert process ?

**What are our concerns -**

- Low cost.
- Low battery consumption.
- Changing payload after deployment.
- Host processor should be able to turn ON/OFF the on-board BLE device. The latency should be low in such case.
- We should be able to monitor Beacon health i.e. if any beacon is down.
- Security.
- Are there any other things we should be concerned with ?? :)

Comment: What kind of central are you planning to have? An iPhone? Is it important that iPhone users can scan your iBeacons in the background?

Comment: I definitely need it to support the use cases when my app would be in background. But I will have both Android and iOS user base. Are you saying may be iBeacon only natively supports scanning in background on iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use iBeacon if you need scanning in background on iOS. Android can scan in background for any advertising payload.

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflow rules do not allow recommendations, but I will answer two embedded questions:

- AltBeacon does not require any certification, but you obviously must meet the spec for it to work with other devices.
- Eddystone similarly does not require pre-certification, but you may optionally do so to have your products listed on Google's website listing of compatible manufacturers.

@Simon-Judge is mostly correct in his answer that iBeacon provides fastest background on iOS.   However, you can detect Eddsystone formats in the background on iOS as they use service advertisements which iOS APIs allow.  This is much slower than iBeacon (typically 10 minutes vs. 5 seconds for iBeacon).  AltBeacon, by comparison cannot be detected at all in the background on iOS as it is a manufacturer advertisement.   The only manufacturer advertisements that can be detected in the background on iOS are iBeacon advertisements.

Comment: There has been a change since i posted the question. We would be going after a BLE vendor. From what you have explained, if I am targeting a iOS user base (along with Android and other platform users) and also want to process the communication between the BLE device and Phone in background, then iBeacon looks to be the only option.